# codeigniter append [removed] message while stripping tags

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter 2.1.4,

if i add

```
>  Hello world <script>alert('hi')</script>
```

in the inputbox.

While processing the value codeigniter adding [removed] text.The output will be like

> Hello world[removed]alert('hi');[removed]

Comment: $this->input->post('fieldname',true)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **strip_tags** function from php

```
echo strip_tags("<b>foo</b>");
```

Results in: foo
And In your case output of

```
echo strip_tags("Hello world <script>alert('hi')</script>");
```

Results in: Hello world alert('hi')

Comment: we can use stri_tags to print the value , what if you want to use codeigniter query builder.

Comment: Give a detail of what you want to accomplish here  ?? To insert in database or just to show or just for fun ?

Comment: @Balaji Whats issue in using $this->db->insert("table_name",array("field"=>strip_tags($this->input->post("fieldname")))); ?

Comment: by default in config we have enabled xss_clean

Comment: Lets assume that you have **Hello world <script>alert('hi')</script>** in your textbox so at the end you want it as **Hello world alert('hi')** Right ?? TO insert in your database I gave you query which will work fine. Not getting what you want to say. As i told you earlier Give a detailed explaination